# How can I join measure data and release information?

Tags: join, pyspark

I try to join two pyspark dataframes. One contains my measurement data, the other one contains release information of my measruement equipment. I want to add the release information to the measurement data like this:

Input:

- measure data:

  | logger_id | measure_date | data |
  | --- | --- | --- |
  | 394 | 2018-07-09T09:25:40 | *some data* |
  | 394 | 2018-08-23T09:51:18 | *other data* |
  | 394 | 2019-04-23T09:51:18 | *other data* |
  | 398 | 2018-01-10T12:15:53 | *more data* |
  | 398 | 2019-10-24T08:10:25 | *other data* |
- release data

  | logger_id | release_date | release_information |
  | --- | --- | --- |
  | 394 | 2018-07-01T00:00:00 | *release information* |
  | 394 | 2019-04-01T00:00:00 | *release information* |
  | 398 | 2018-01-01T00:00:00 | *release information* |
  | 398 | 2019-07-01T00:00:00 | *release information* |

and I want an output like that:

| logger_id | measure_date | data | release_date | release_information |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 394 | 2018-07-09T09:25:40 | *some data* | 2018-07-01T00:00:00 | *release information* |
| 394 | 2018-08-23T09:51:18 | *other data* | 2018-07-01T00:00:00 | *release information* |
| 394 | 2019-04-23T09:51:18 | *other data* | 2019-04-01T00:00:00 | *release information* |
| 398 | 2018-01-10T12:15:53 | *more data* | 2018-01-01T00:00:00 | *release information* |
| 398 | 2019-10-24T08:10:25 | *other data* | 2019-07-01T00:00:00 | *release information* |

I've already tried

```
cond = [release_data.release_date < measure_data.measure_date, release_data.logger_id == measure_data.logger_id]
measure_data.join(release_data, cond, how='fullouter')
```

But in the resulting dataframe I get the release data with 'null' columns of the measure dataframe

I also considered iterating through my measuredata dataframe and adding the release information for every row, but for it is really large, I don't wanna do that

Comment: Can you explain why `release data` with `logger_id` 394 and `release_data``2018-07-01T00:00:00` joined with  measure date `2018-07-09T09:25:40` and not `2018-08-23T09:51:18` or `2019-04-23T09:51:18`

Comment: I got my first logger-release on 2018-07-01 (lets call it v1) and got some measures on 2018-07-09 and 2018-08-23. on 2019-04-01 I got an update (v2) and new measure on 2019-04-23. Now I want to add the release information from release v1 to the measures, I got with this release version. after I got v2, I want to add the release information of v2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can transform `release_df` to include a column that finds the until when a release is valid, for this [`lead`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.lead.html) can be used.

Once the `release_valid_end` is included, then the join condition would change to find date comparison checks between `measure_date` and
`release_date` and `release_valid_end`.

```py
from datetime import datetime
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window as W

measure_data = [(394, datetime.strptime("2018-07-09T09:25:40", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S"), "some data",),
                (394, datetime.strptime("2018-08-23T09:51:18", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S"), "other data",),
                (394, datetime.strptime("2019-04-23T09:51:18", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S"), "other data",),
                (398, datetime.strptime("2018-01-10T12:15:53", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S"), "more data",),
                (398, datetime.strptime("2019-10-24T08:10:25", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S"), "other data",), ]

release_data = [(394, datetime.strptime("2018-07-01T00:00:00", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S"), "release information",),
                (394, datetime.strptime("2019-04-01T00:00:00", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S"), "release information",),
                (398, datetime.strptime("2018-01-01T00:00:00", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S"), "release information",),
                (398, datetime.strptime("2019-07-01T00:00:00", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S"), "release information",), ]

measure_df = spark.createDataFrame(measure_data, ("logger_id", "measure_date", "data",))
release_df = spark.createDataFrame(release_data, ("logger_id", "release_date", "release_information",))

world_end_date = datetime.strptime("2999-12-31T00:00:00", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")

window_spec = W.partitionBy("logger_id").orderBy(F.asc("release_date"))

release_validity_df = release_df.withColumn("release_valid_end", 
                                            F.lead("release_date", offset=1, default=world_end_date).over(window_spec))

(measure_df.join(release_validity_df, 
                ((measure_df["logger_id"] == release_validity_df["logger_id"]) & 
                 ((measure_df["measure_date"] >= release_validity_df["release_date"]) &
                  (measure_df["measure_date"] < release_validity_df["release_valid_end"]))
                ))
).select(measure_df["logger_id"], "measure_date", "data", "release_date", "release_information").show()
```

### Output

```
+---------+-------------------+----------+-------------------+-------------------+
|logger_id|       measure_date|      data|       release_date|release_information|
+---------+-------------------+----------+-------------------+-------------------+
|      398|2018-01-10 12:15:53| more data|2018-01-01 00:00:00|release information|
|      398|2019-10-24 08:10:25|other data|2019-07-01 00:00:00|release information|
|      394|2018-07-09 09:25:40| some data|2018-07-01 00:00:00|release information|
|      394|2018-08-23 09:51:18|other data|2018-07-01 00:00:00|release information|
|      394|2019-04-23 09:51:18|other data|2019-04-01 00:00:00|release information|
+---------+-------------------+----------+-------------------+-------------------+
```

Comment: Thank you verry much. What if I have the same measure date and release date? Can I specify, which date I want to take?

Comment: @Joka I have modified the answer for explicit date check in the join condition, this way you can decide how to handle the bounding conditions